# SqlDataReader not returning any data from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in my SQL Server database which executes fine:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadStates]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT stateabbrev 
    FROM states 
    ORDER BY stateabbrev
END
GO
```

Here is my C# code; `sdrData` has been initialized and seems to be correct but the results set is empty. Please help.

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("LoadStates", sqlConn))
{
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // set up the parameters that the Stored Procedure expects
    //sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@States", SqlDbType.Char, 2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    using (SqlDataReader sdrData = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdrData.Read())
        {
            string strDBNme = sdrData.ToString();
            //string strDBNme = (string)sdrData["States"];
            cmbxACState.Items.Add(strDBNme);
        }

        sdrData.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       SqlDataReader sdrData  = null;
        // create a connection object
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(create your sql connection string here );

// create a command object
  SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("LoadStates", conn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            // open the connection
            conn.Open();                
            sdrData = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdrData.Read())
                    {
                        //string strDBNme = sdrData.ToString();
                        string strDBNme = (string)sdrData["States"];
                        cmbxACState.Items.Add(strDBNme);
                    }

        }
        finally
        {
            // 3. close the reader
            if (sdrData != null)
            {
                sdrData.Close();
            }

            // close the connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: #Ramdeo angh -- I tried this and still the same results.  My connection string is already opened, I do it in a step before.  Is there a way to trace the call to the sql server and see what happens with the call?

Comment: look at the new  answer that i have posted. it's  working and tested . you need to change in your code.  open your connection before SQL command statement.  SqlConn.openConnection().  and next  change is in while loop..  string strDBNme = (string)sdrData["stateabbrev"];   at place of  states need to put stateabbrev.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strDBNme = (string)sdrData["stateabbrev"];
```

Comment: I don't get to this statement, string strDBNme = (string)sdrData["stateabbrev"];.  The sdrData.Read( ) doesn't return anythig

Comment: You can extract each column of the row with a numeric indexer like this, but it isn’t very readable. So use Column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StackDemo"]
                 .ConnectionString;
         using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
         {

             connection.Open();
             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoadStates", connection))
             {
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                 using (SqlDataReader sdrData = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                     while (sdrData.Read())
                     {
                       Console.WriteLine( (string)sdrData["stateabbrev"]);

                     }

                     sdrData.Close();
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: it's working demo. just replace your connection string  with <b>StackDemo</b>.